# Google map custom marker link not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

Trying to get my markers pointing to another pages.
Copied the answers from previously solved cases. Still doesn't work.
The map with the markers comes up OK. Even the titles are there however, the links are not working.
Keep having message "Uncaught ReferenceError:marker is not defined".
What I'm doing wrong here?? Ran out of ideas.
Can somebody have a look to help me out of this.
Gigantic thanks;

```
<script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=ko&key=AIzaSyA3WDZ1KfeUb_Q-SxtIRE2wZ4RBieuGl7s"
    type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script>
 function Goog2() {
     var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('Google_map');
     var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.80257,15.9371),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
     var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

     var myLatLng0 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.80257,15.9371);
     var myLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.805455,15.983761);
     var myLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.738822, 16.068278);
     var myLatLng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.803816, 15.993573);

    var markers = [];


    markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng0,
         map: map,
         url: '/cocohouse/location/CH_location_en.html',
         icon: "/images/ariranglogoimage28_2.png",
         title: 'Coco House',
     });
     markers[1] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng1,
         map: map,
         icon: "/images/cocohouse/location/train26.png",
         url:"/cocohouse/location/to_CH3_en.html",
         title: 'Train Terminal',

     });
     markers[2] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng2,
         map: map,
         icon: "/images/cocohouse/location/airport32.png",
         url:"/cocohouse/location/to_CH1_en.html",
         title: 'Airport',
     });
     markers[3] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng3,
         map: map,
         icon: "/images/cocohouse/location/bus26.png",
         url:"/cocohouse/location/to_CH2_en.html",
         title: 'Bus Terminal',
     });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Goog2);

    for ( i = 0; i < markers.lenght; i++ ) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
          window.location.href = this.url; 
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError:marker is not defined" : have you a line number?

Comment: markers.lenght : just a typo? markers.length

Comment: the message comes up at ....markers.lenght..... line.  When I put #4 there instead the Error message moves down to the following line.

Comment: So it's "Uncaught ReferenceError:markerS is not defined"?

Comment: corrected the type.  The same message still at the same place...

Comment: yup... small S there in markers

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'markers' in a context which it's not defined.
'markers' is declared in Goog2 function and use outside.

Try (not tested):

```
<script>
  function Goog2() {
     var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('Google_map');
     var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.80257,15.9371),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
     var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

     var myLatLng0 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.80257,15.9371);
     var myLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.805455,15.983761);
     var myLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.738822, 16.068278);
     var myLatLng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.803816, 15.993573);
    var markers = [];
    markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng0,
         map: map,
         url: '/cocohouse/location/CH_location_en.html',
         icon: "/images/ariranglogoimage28_2.png",
         title: 'Coco House',
     });
     markers[1] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng1,
         map: map,
         icon: "/images/cocohouse/location/train26.png",
         url:"/cocohouse/location/to_CH3_en.html",
         title: 'Train Terminal',

     });
     markers[2] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng2,
         map: map,
         icon: "/images/cocohouse/location/airport32.png",
         url:"/cocohouse/location/to_CH1_en.html",
         title: 'Airport',
     });
     markers[3] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng3,
         map: map,
         icon: "/images/cocohouse/location/bus26.png",
         url:"/cocohouse/location/to_CH2_en.html",
         title: 'Bus Terminal',
     });

     for ( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
          window.location.href = this.url; 
        });
     }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Goog2);

</script>
```

Comment: Geting somewhere!! Error message is gone.

Comment: try to add a console.log(this.url) message in the click listener to see if listener is working and url is correct.

Comment: is that what you were reffering

Comment: for ( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {   google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
window.location.href = this.url;
console.log(this.url);     
});
}

Comment: here is the ling to my source..
http://www.arirangcroatia.com/cocohouse/location/CH_location_en.html

Answer (score 0):

`markers.lenght;` should read `markers.length;`

```
for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
        window.location.href = this.url;
    });
}
```

`markers` needs to be defined before you use it.

You are calling `Goog2` on window load but your loop is executed before this event and before your array is populated.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the click listeners before the markers exist.  Move that loop inside the `Goog2` function.  Example code snippet (changed the markers to publicly available icons, the URLs to arbitrary public ones, fixed the spelling error on markers.length).

```js
 function Goog2() {
   var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('Google_map');
   var mapOptions = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.80257, 15.9371),
     zoom: 10,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
   var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

   var myLatLng0 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.80257, 15.9371);
   var myLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.805455, 15.983761);
   var myLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.738822, 16.068278);
   var myLatLng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.803816, 15.993573);

   var markers = [];


   markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng0,
     map: map,
     url: 'http://google.com',
     icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png",
     title: 'Coco House',
   });
   markers[1] = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng1,
     map: map,
     icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
     url: "http://yahoo.com",
     title: 'Train Terminal',

   });
   markers[2] = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng2,
     map: map,
     icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png",
     url: "http://maps.google.com",
     title: 'Airport',
   });
   markers[3] = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng3,
     map: map,
     icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/purple.png",
     url: "http://www.cnn.com",
     title: 'Bus Terminal',
   });

   for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
       window.location.href = this.url;
     });
   }
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Goog2);
```

```css
html,
body,
#Google_map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="Google_map" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: If your issue has been addressed, please [accept one of the answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)